# Using MySQL the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on creating `Rest API` using the visual studio in asp.net MVC. The database I am using is `MySQL`. I am getting below error while running the API.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.   DataAccess  D:\Work\DOT NET API\RestWithMySQL\DataAccess\ProductsModel.edmx 7
```

I have two projects in my single solution. `Data Access` project in which I have added the model and `RestWithMySQL` project in which I have added my control and the model is added as a reference in it.

When I click on the error I am redirected to the following section

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
  <Schema Namespace="ProductsModel.Store" Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="5.5" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityType Name="product">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Name" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" />
      <Property Name="Price" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="Category" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="ProductsModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="product" EntityType="Self.product" Schema="accurate_dev" store:Type="Tables" />
    </EntityContainer>
  </Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
```

[image]

My config file is below

```
<connectionStrings>
<!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-RestWithMySQL-20170911031521.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-RestWithMySQL-20170911031521;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
<add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProductsModel.csdl|res://*/ProductsModel.ssdl|res://*/ProductsModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; Server=localhost; Uid=root; Database=accurate_dev; Port=3306;SslMode=Preferred" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
 <!--<remove name="LocalMySqlServer" /><add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProductsModel.csdl|res://*/ProductsModel.ssdl|res://*/ProductsModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=;Database=accurate_dev;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />-->
```

I have searched for every solution related to it but still can't able to get the desired result.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/, so it depends how you connect to MySQL. Notice that providerName is not necessary. For example I use dotNetConnector and my connection string is like: <add name="DbContext" connectionString="User Id=user;Password=passwd;Host=myHost;Database=myDb;Persist Security Info=True" />

Comment: @JCM Tried but still no success

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've referenced MySql.Data with NuGet, make sure you have a system.data section in your web/app.config to override the factory for your version. The version should match that of your nuget reference.

e.g.

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: This what exactly what I needed. I got all sorts of weird errors without it (e.g. a NullReferenceException thrown down in some get manifest token library method)